# No output returned from plugin but services shows ok

Tags: nagios, ubuntu-14.04, nrpe

I'm trying to check the system memory by using [check_memory.pl](https://github.com/justintime/nagios-plugins/tree/master/check_mem) and the following command setup:

In the nrpe.cfg on the remote host

```
    command[check_mem]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mem -f -w 20 -c 10
```

Service on the Nagios server:

```
define service{
use                     generic-service
host_name               Hostname     ;winserver
service_description     Check Memory
check_command           check_nrpe!check_mem
}
```

When I run the command on the remote host like this

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mem  -f -w 20 -c 10
```

I get:

```
OK - 73.6% (6013416 kB) free.|TOTAL=8175616KB;;;; USED=2162200KB;6540492;7358054;; FREE=6013416KB;;;; CACHES=2021812KB;;;;
```

When I run

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H host-ip -c check_mem
or
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H host-ip -c check_mem -a -w 20 -c 10
```

or any list of args

I receive :

```
   Wrong Syntax: custom_check_mem 
   Usage: custom_check_mem [-w|--warning]<percent free> [-c|--critical]<percent free>
```

but the Web is showing **Service is OK** and a message like this:

(No output returned from plugin)
Wrong Syntax: custom_check_mem

Usage: custom_check_mem [-w--warning] [-c|--critical]

I tried this plugin on other servers it work well but I don't do what is missing in the setup for this one.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: are you running the plugin manually as the nagios (or nrpe) user?

Comment: Both: manually on the Nagios core and through Nagios-Nrpe;  they gives the output mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like that plugin is crap. There are at least a dozen different `check_memory` variants out there.

Perhaps try [this one](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_memory/details).

Comment: I changed the plugin and things worked just fine. Wonder how it works on different boxes . Anyways, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Your command definition in NRPE seems wrong

```
command[check_mem]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mem -f -w 20 -c 10
```

Since check_mem does not seem to have a `-f` argument.

On the other side, check_mem seems to exit with 0 on wrong arguments, which is not a good behavior for Nagios plugins... (the should exit with 3 - UNKNOWN)

Nagios / Icinga only gets the "status" from the command's return code, the output is merely information for the user.

Comment: I tried removing the -f from the command and tried other arguments still no change. I'm not sure why would it work on 3 other remotes but not this one. Even with the same plugin, I copied the same file from the working one to this one and same results. Do you think there is a package or something missing on the server? I noticed different outputs on this one though...